# JBoss Web Service Client alternative to Glassfish Client

Tags: java, web-services, jboss, glassfish

Glassfish gives a really nice tester page once you deploy your webservice and you can quickly and easily test your webservice (client side).  I have to use JBoss, I can't seem to find any alternative to that in JBoss, the best I came up with is adding the page myself.  Isn't there any quicker way to auto generate a page from the webservice?